# What is PATH in Windows OS? Are there ways i can practice this concept?

Tags: windows, path

I'm just starting out with programming..

Im working through Al Sweigart's book ATBSWP, and im starting a chapter where i have to write python scripts.

What exactly is PATH, im just having a hard time understanding the concept of it.
Is there anything i can practice that will help me understand it?

I tried looking up Youtube videos on the topic, but they weren't as straight forward as i imagined.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PATH is a system environmental variable that holds the paths of directories, which contents can be run from command lines or the Run command (Win + R) without specifying its path.

You can edit PATH on Windows like this:

```
    Press the Windows key (or click the Windows Search bar) >  
    search for "Edit Environment Variables" (or just "Environment") >  
    click the "Edit Environment Variables" option > click "Environment variables..." at the bottom right of the new window >  
    click "Path" at the "User variables for user [your name]" list to change only for you or click "Path" at the "System variables" list to change for the entire PC >  
    click "Edit..." under the list you picked >  
    Select "New" on the right >  
    Enter/paste your path or select "Browse..." >  
    Click "OK" on every window you have opened.
```

For example, if I have the `C:\Program Files\CommandLineApp` directory that contains a CommandLineApp.exe file in PATH, then I can run the CommandLineApp.exe from the command line either by specifying the path (i.e. `C:\Program Files\CommandLineApp\CommandLineApp.exe`) or by running the command `CommandLineApp.exe` or simply just `CommandLineApp`.

If I didn't have the CommandLineApp directory in PATH, I could only run the executable by specifying the full path or by having the directory open in CMD (using the `CD` command)

Comment: Note that this is not totally specific to Windows, the same concept exists in other operating systems, in slightly different implementations. In Linux/UNIX/Mac OS for example it's also `PATH`, but the separator is a colon instead of a semicolon.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Not just the command-line (which is off-topic StackOverflow), but also `ShellExecute`, `CreateProcess`, `LoadLibrary`, and a myriad other OS functions use the PATH environment variable when searching for files.  On Windows it's the same variable controlling all, while other OSes separate out e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`